# Have a value be printed with a varying number of spaces before it?

Tags: c, spaces

Is this possible? So if I were to print a value, I could print it with, say, 3 spaces before the actual output instead of four?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: Incrementing a concatentation function that adds space to the end.

Comment: Would I be able to start with a bunch of spaces and decrement the values? I mean starting with 10 spaces and ending with 0.

Comment: Are you talking about numbers? text? What is the type of the value you want to print?

Comment: it would help if you show us an example in code, so you can get a better answer. but sounds posible from here also.

Answer (score 4):

printf has a * format for dynamically specifying a minimum field width:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int value = 5;
    const char *name = "LaDonna";
    double value2 = 200.55;
    const char *space = " ";
    for (int width = 0; width < 10; width++)
        printf("%*d %*.2f %*s\n",width,value,width,value2,width + 5,name);
    for (int width=1; width < 5; width++)
        printf("%*s%d\n",width,space,width);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
5 200.55 LaDonna
5 200.55 LaDonna
 5 200.55 LaDonna
  5 200.55  LaDonna
   5 200.55   LaDonna
    5 200.55    LaDonna
     5 200.55     LaDonna
      5  200.55      LaDonna
       5   200.55       LaDonna
        5    200.55        LaDonna
 1
  2
   3
    4
```