# To understand %*d and if (( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 ) || ( n <= 0 )) in c

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, format-specifiers

I have to print this pattern in c

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 2 1 2 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

And I found this code associated with it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()  
{ 
    while ( 1 ) 
    { 
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " ); 

        int n; 

        if ( ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 ) || ( n <= 0 ) ) break; 

        if ( INT_MAX / 2 < n )  
        { 
            n = INT_MAX / 2; 
        } 

        int width = 1; 

        for ( int tmp = n; tmp /= 10; ) ++width; 

        putchar( '\n' ); 

        int m = 2 * n - 1; 

        for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ) 
        { 
            for ( int j = 0; j < m; j++ ) 
            {
                int value1 = abs( n - i - 1 ) + 1;
                int value2 = abs( n - j - 1 ) + 1;

                printf( "%*d ", width, value1 < value2 ? value2 : value1 );
            } 
            putchar( '\n' ); 
        } 

        putchar( '\n' ); 
    } 

    return 0; 
 }
```

I want to know why in this statement`scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1` is used

```
if (( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 ) || ( n <= 0 ));
```

and also how single format specifier is accepting two values here

```
printf( "%*d ", width, value1 < value2 ? value2 : value1 );
```

Why % and * are used together`"%*d"`??

Comment: `*` means to get the field width from the argument, instead of hard-coding it into the format string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450853/have-a-value-be-printed-with-a-varying-number-of-spaces-before-it/12451132#12451132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `scanf("%d", &n)` will attempt to read in an integer into `n` and, if successful, will return the value `1` (actually, it will return the number of things successfully read but, since you're only asking for one thing, that's the most you'll get back). If it fails, you'll get something else.

Hence the comparison with `1`  is to ensure it worked. If you don't get `1`, something went wrong.

The statement `printf( "%*d ", width, something)` is actually closely related to `printf("%5d", something)` (which would print a field *at least* five characters wide) but, rather than the fixed `5`, the variable `width` is used instead.

Hence the two `printf` calls below are equivalent:

```
int val = 42;
int wid = 5;
printf("%5d", val);
printf("%*d", wid, val);
```

Since `width` always appears to be `1` in the code you've given, I'm not sure *why* it was done that way. It seems to me it would be easier to just use `%d` as the format specifier.

---

If you're interested in a more concise and structured solution, you may find this helpful. Don't use this if it's educational work since the intent there is to learn to do it yourself, but it's helpful to see another approach.

This code factors out the logic for doing a single line, printing enough elements to go from the maximum down to one then back up again (but setting a minimum value to print based on the line).

The main code then just prints out enough lines so that the middle value of each line goes from the maximum down to one than back up again (basically the same logic used for each line).

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Code to print out a single line, values going from max down to min then back up.

static void outLine(int max, int min) {
    for (int i = max; i > 0; i--) printf("%d ", i < min ? min : i);
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) printf("%d ", i < min ? min : i);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main()  {
    while ( 1 ) {
        // Get the value, <1 means stop.

        int n;
        printf( "\nEnter a non-negative number (< 1 = exit): " );
        if ((scanf("%d", &n) != 1) || (n <= 0)) break;

        // Do each line, max down to 1 then back up.

        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) outLine(n, i);
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) outLine(n, i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Transcript is, as requested:

```
pax> ./testProg

Enter a non-negative number (< 1 = exit): 2
2 2 2
2 1 2
2 2 2

Enter a non-negative number (< 1 = exit): 3
3 3 3 3 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 2 1 2 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 3 3 3 3

Enter a non-negative number (< 1 = exit): 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 2 1 2 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4

Enter a non-negative number (< 1 = exit): -42
```

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (7.21.6.4 The scanf function)

> **Returns**
>
> 3 The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
>   failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
>   **Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items assigned**, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the
>   event of an early matching failure.

In this if statement

```
if (( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 ) || ( n <= 0 ));
```

the sub-expression `( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 )` whether the call of `scanf` was successful that is whether the variable `n` got a value from the user. If so (that is in the case of success) then the second sub-expression `( n <= 0 )` checks whether the inputted value is non-positive.

That is if either the call of scanf was not successful or the user eetered a non-positive value the control is passed outside the while loop due to the break statement. As a result the program finishes its execution.

In this call of printf

```
printf( "%*d ", width, value1 < value2 ? value2 : value1 );
```

the format conversion specifier `%*d` specifies that the width of the outputted field (`*`) will be set as an argument of the call (`width`) and the expression `value1 < value2 ? value2 : value1` selects the maximum value between these two value `value1` and `value2`.

You could rewrite this call pf printf the following way

```
if ( value1 < value2 )
{
    printf( "%*d ", width, value2 );
}
else
{
    printf( "%*d ", width, value1 );
}
```